# vector scalar multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

When one define a special vector scalar multiplication, does this normally supposed to have an effect on a multiplication between the scalars themselves?

For example, $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{F}$, ${\bf v}\in\mathbb{V}$ , $f:\mathbb{F}\to \mathbb{F}$
$$\alpha \odot {\bf v} \equiv f(\alpha) {\bf v}$$

Now I want to verify associativity of this scalar multiplication, shall I check
$$\alpha \odot(\beta\odot {\bf v}) = (\alpha\odot\beta)\odot{\bf v}$$
where $\alpha\odot\beta$ needs to be explicitly defined, e.g. $\alpha\odot\beta=f(\alpha)f(\beta)$
or, alternatively I have to check
$$\alpha \odot(\beta\odot {\bf v}) = (\alpha\beta)\odot{\bf v}$$
where $\alpha\beta$ is a regular multiplication in this field?

The question is rises from the claim that $\mathbb{C}^n$ is a vector space over complex numbers with regular addition and a $\alpha\odot{\bf v}=Re(\alpha){\bf v}$ which may work with the first definition and won't work with the second, since $Re(z_1 z_2)\ne Re(z_1)Re(z_2)$. So I guess either, the claim isn't correct or I missing something:)

**Finally**

See own answer below, also the claim above which I've intialy assumed true fails apart as false.

Comment: $\alpha\odot\beta$ is not defined for $V\neq F$. But $\alpha\cdot \beta$ is defined in $F$.

Comment: please see the edit

Comment: Why doesn’t $f(\alpha)=\Re(\alpha)$ work with the first definition? $\alpha\odot(\beta\odot\mathbf v)=\Re(\alpha)(\Re(\beta)\mathbf v)=\Re(\Re(\alpha)\Re(\beta))\mathbf v=(\alpha\odot\beta)\mathbf v$, or am I missing something?

Comment: I messed it a little, it won't work with the second - going to fix it

Comment: Seems like you’ve got an answer, then—it’s the first one.

Comment: well, this would make the associativity, however this doesn't mean this is a normal thing.  Although the non uniqueness of unit scalar under this multiplication fails the definition of the field and make the claim invalid, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,

The definition of a vector $\mathbb{V}$ space over a  field $\mathbb{F}$ talking about a vector multiplication to a scalar $\alpha in\mathbb{F}$. From the definition of the field it is supposes the scalar addition and multiplication with given (Abelian group) properties. Therefore associativity should be checked versus the regular field's multiplication, i.e.
$$\alpha \odot(\beta\odot {\bf v}) = (\alpha\beta)\odot{\bf v}.$$

Otherwise, the definition of vector space should have defined additional operator between the scalars which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbf w=\beta\odot\mathbf v$. Then you must have $\alpha\odot(\beta\odot\mathbf v)=\alpha\odot\mathbf w=f(\alpha)\mathbf w=f(\alpha)(\beta\odot\mathbf v)=f(\alpha)f(\beta)\mathbf v$. So, you must have $\alpha\odot\beta=f(\alpha)f(\beta)$. I hope that with this definition of scalar multiplication, you still have a field.

On the other hand (per Bye_World’s comment), if this is the case, then $(\alpha\odot\beta)\mathbf v = f(\alpha\odot\beta)\mathbf v = f(f(\alpha)f(\beta))\mathbf v$, which constrains the functions that can be used for this type of scalar multiplication.

Comment: yes this is what I was thinking about if you see the edit...

Comment: Except if $\alpha\odot\beta=f(\alpha)f(\beta)$ then $(\alpha\odot\beta)\odot \mathbf v=f(f(\alpha)f(\beta))\mathbf v$ not $f(\alpha)f(\beta)\mathbf v$.

Comment: yes, since associativity is needed for removing the brackets, look like this requires $f^2=f$, i.e.  a projection